rtf-stream-parser npm : Super expression must either be null or a function error with DeEncapsulate
I'm facing an issue with the DeEncapsulate class from the rtf-stream-parser library in my Angular application. I'm getting the following error:
**polyfills.js:5887 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
        at _inherits (polyfills.js:5887:11)
        at vendor.js:71541:3
        at 1Z4d (vendor.js:71970:2)**

vendor.js:
   var DeEncapsulate = /*#__PURE__*/function (_stream_1$Transform) {
  _inherits(DeEncapsulate, _stream_1$Transform);

//component
import * as iconvLite from 'iconv-lite';
import { deEncapsulateSync } from 'rtf-stream-parser';

const rtf = '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\fromtext{{{{{{hello}}}}}}}';
const result = deEncapsulateSync(rtf, { decode: iconvLite.decode });
console.log(result); // { mode: 'text', text: 'hello' }

i have installed in my project:

npm i stream-browserify
npm i process
npm i buffer
npm i rtf-stream-parser
npm i iconv-lite
npm i stream

and included in polyfill.ts
(window as any).global = window;
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import * as process from 'process';
import * as stream from 'stream-browserify';

(window as any).Buffer = Buffer;
(window as any).process = process;
(window as any).stream = stream;

